# Python triple quote literal syntax not highlighting correctly in mobile app

Tags: bug, code-formatting, ios-app

I recently wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040151/6622817) to a question. With the same code block, when viewing from the mobile app, the syntax highlighting is completely messed up, but when I viewed it from safari, it's all fine. Is this a bug?

---

iOS Mobile app view:

[image]

---

Safari/Website view:

[image]

Comment: Wonder if it's similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244600/syntax-highlighting-in-app-differs-from-normal-web-view

Comment: @JonClements: that one looks like a color scheme issue, this looks more like a parser issue.

Comment: @Martijn indeed - I wasn't very clear. The colour issue was fixed and there was no parsing issue (none I recall seeing anyway - and I'd like to think I'd have noticed that one fairly swiftly). So this looks  like a reversion of some sort in the new SO app.